# Как добавить data атрибут в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Код, которым пытаюсь добавить data атрибут:

```js
var content = 11;
$('.kuda').attr('data-content',content);
```

Вот сам массив

```js
tenant_fields[0]=['Pudge', '<a class="kuda" href="" data-html="true" data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover"><img src="/images/heroes_small/pudge_small.png" style="width: 26px; height: 15px; margin-top: 0; margin-right: 4px" alt=""></a>'];
```

не могу достучаться до него. Если код в чистом html, то все ок. А тут даже не знаю.

Comment: как связаны между собой эти два фрагмента кода?

Comment: Поправил, не то немного скопировал.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь в строку которая у вас хранится в массиве, вставить данные инструментами для работы DOM деревом?

Comment: Видимо делаю дичь, не знаю как правильно тут поступить...

Comment: У вас есть массив, где хранится html. Вам надо его отредактировать внутри массива, после чего вставить в DOM? Или какая стоит задача?

Comment: Это в плагине для ckeditor. Есть массив из подобных данных. при выборе одного из них, его значние(тот html код) идет в редактор. Мне нужно для каждого из них добавить data атрибут в этот html, который уже в массиве.

Comment: как-то так это работает https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMYNJX

Comment: Никогда не сталкивался с CKeditor, вот и удивился) Внизу по идее вам ответили)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var tenant_fields = [];
tenant_fields[0]=['Pudge', '<a class="kuda" href="" data-html="true" data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover"><img src="/images/heroes_small/pudge_small.png" style="width: 26px; height: 15px; margin-top: 0; margin-right: 4px" alt=""></a>'];

var div = $("<div></div>");
div.html(tenant_fields[0][1]).find("a").attr("data-content", "test");
tenant_fields[0][1] = div.html();

console.log(tenant_fields[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```